# How to clone git repository with GitPython using SSH key with passphrase

Tags: git, python-3.x, ssh, gitpython

I'm currently trying to figure out how to use GitPython to clone a remote repository with an SSH key that has a passphrase (using Python 3.5.2). The documentation hasn't been very helpful in this regard:

> You can also specify per-call custom environments using a new context manager on the Git command, e.g. for using a specific SSH key. The following example works with git starting at v2.3:

```
ssh_cmd = 'ssh -i id_deployment_key'
with repo.git.custom_environment(GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh_cmd):
    repo.remotes.origin.fetch()
```

What I gather from this is that I can load a specific key via the ssh_cmd variable and GitPython will load it, but how does the passphrase get entered?  Will the user be prompted?  Also, I'm trying to clone from a remote, the code above assumes you've already done that or created a local repository first? Again, it's not very clear, to me at least.

Is what I'm trying to do possible and if so can you provide examples? I'd love to see a simple workflow of:

1. Clone a remote repository
2. Add changes.
3. Commit.
4. Push.

All with an SSH key that has a passphrase.

I should also mention I'm doing this on a Windows 7 machine, which pexpect is not compatible with.

Comment: You could try to implement a program to obtain user credentials, and point to it with the `GIT_ASKPASS` environmant variable. More information can be found here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Environment-Variables.

Comment: Alternatively, you could implement the `GIT_SSH` variable, and set it up to provide credentials for you.

Comment: Do you happen to have a working example?

Comment: No, however, you can try these out with the git command-line directly, without the need to involve GitPython from the very beginning.

Comment: Setup an ssh-agent and add the ssh key to ssh0agent. Then ssh will not have to prompt for the passphrase.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I have this same question.  It was never answered (4.5 years later).  There has to be a way to use GitPython with a ssh key, this is such a basic feature.  I do not understand why it is documented.